# Which fields should an encrypted message contain that is encrypted using AES and PBDKF2?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm developing an App that can download content from a backend server. The content is stored on the device and thus needs to be encrypted. Currently, I use AES128 and derive a key using PBDKF2. A part of the passphrase for PBDKF2 is obtained from an external device the app can connect to and sent to the server when the app wants to download content.

The flow is as follows:

1. The app connects to an external device and obtains some information `x`
2. The app sends a request to the backend asking for a certain file and includes `x` in the request
3. The backend uses `x` to create a passphrase and `PBDKF2WithHmacSHA1`to generate the key for `AES`
4. The backend encrypts the requested file using the generated key and `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`
5. The backend constructs a message in the following format: `<iteration>.<salt>.<encrypted-data>` where `<iterations>` is the number of iterations passed to `PBDKF2`, `<salt>` is a randomly generated salt for `PBDKF2`, and `<encrypted-data>` is the encrypted file data.
6. The backend sends the message back to the client
7. The client deconstructs the message and decrypts the encrypted data using the provided parameters.

My question is: Is it safe to create the message according to this schema (concatenation of the input parameters and encrypted data)? The client knows how to construct the passphrase using `x` - code obfuscation should make it as hard as possible to figure out how it's done:

(I know that the plain file will be in the heap/memory of the device after decryption, but only for very short period of time)

Comment: Someone tapping the commonication channel has all the information needed to decrypt: x and the encrypted message. So this scheme is not secure at all.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate (and get you better answers) on [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com). AFAIK, schemes like this have some notion of pre-shared knowledge between the device and the backend which does not get communicated afterwards.

Comment: I've read other examples where there is no server involved and where it is stated that the salt and IV is considered public and stored alongside the encrypted data. I don't get how I - given my scenario - can make it more secure :-/ Assuming a possible attacker knows every parameter (iteration, salt, iv, key stretching and aes algorithm) - the only thing he does not know is the passphrase - which is only obtained when decryption is need, but not from the user but from a peripheral device